# no network connection

Tags: networking, centos

I have problems with my network connection `eth0`
I created `/ifcfg-eth0` file since it was not present at `/network-scripts`.
I tried `ifconfig` which does not display `eth0`. I have `wlan0` which gets connected at ease.

I have checked `service NetworkManager status` and `service network status` all is fine.

I also ran:

```
$ lspci | grep -i net
03:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet(rev 10)
```

Comment: Did you actually create `/ifcfg-eth0`? What's `/network-scripts`? Do you mean `/etc/network-scripts` or similar? What are the contents of this file you created? Are you connecting over wireless or ethernet? What kind of hardware? Can we see the output of `ifconfig`? Basically, we need a _lot_ more detail than this.

Comment: Is your network interface visible if you do `sudo lspci|grep net`?

Comment: Is it possible that CentOS uses another naming convention for Ethernet interfaces? My Fedora installation calls the Ethernet interface `p5p1` whereas my Debian installation calls it `eth0` (same interface).

Comment: @terdon **/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0** was created by since it was not present

Comment: @sabayonUser  i tried lspci|grep -i net it shows `03:00.0 Ethernet Controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet(rev 10)`